# how to use break in forEach in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

In reactjs-babel app i occurred strange behavior trying to use `break` in `forEach`

```
    var SomeElement = React.CreateClass({
        ... ,
        getMessageStatus: function getMessageStatus(message) {
            var states = this.state.messages_states;
            var status = undefined;
            states.forEach(function (messageEntity) {
                if (messageEntity.id == message.id && messageEntity.is_question == message.is_question) {
                    status = messageEntity.status;
                    break; // - this is not working 
                }
            });
            return status;
        },
        ...
        });
```

the break saids it `Cannot determine target for 'break'` in PhpStorm and Babel repl tells like `repl: Unsyntactic break`
how to use break properly ?

Comment: thanks, but how to interrupt the cycle then ?

Comment: Can you use `.find()`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no in-built ability to `break` in `forEach`. To interrupt execution you would have to throw an exception of some sort. eg.

```
var BreakException= {};

try {
    [1,2,3].forEach(function(el) {
        if(el === 1) throw BreakException;
    });
} catch(e) {
    if (e!==BreakException) throw e;
}
```

JavaScript exceptions aren't terribly pretty. A traditional `for` loop might be more appropriate if you really need to `break` inside it.

Instead, use of [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
[1,2,3].some(function(el) {
    return el === 1;
});
```

This works because `some` returns `true` as soon as any of the callbacks, executed in array order, return `true`, short-circuiting the execution of the rest.

`some`, its inverse [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) (which will stop on a `return false`), and `forEach` are all ECMAScript Fifth Edition methods which will need to be added to the `Array.prototype` on browsers where they're missing.

Comment: Using `every` worked for me.

Comment: `some` worked for me perfectly. Thank you. @Tirthraj.

Answer (score 8):

There is no need for `forEach` when you want to `break` on the first occurrence. Just use [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead.

```
 status = states.find((messageEntity) => 
     messageEntity.id == message.id && messageEntity.is_question == message.is_question
 ).status;
```

Comment: Should be marked as answer IMO

Comment: unless you need to support really old browsers (IE11 and less), IE mobile, opera mini, etc ... https://caniuse.com/#search=find

Comment: Then just use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill).